# Mapping a dictionary with Continent: Country to a DataFrame with a Country Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column df['Country']. I have created a dictionary with all of the continents as keys and the values as a list of the corresponding countries.

`continents = { "North America" : ["Canada","Mexico","United States"]}`

I would like to map this to my dataframe where it creates a column with each value in df['Country'] corresponding continent.

I have tried the below but it returns a column of NA values

`df['Continents'] = df['Country'].map(continents)`

Do I need to create a function to map the continents or can I use the pandas .map() method?

Comment: The dictionary needs to be built the other way. `{'Canada': 'North America',...` the keys should be the values in the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong format for your dictionary, you need the reverse (and no list).

You can use this to get the right format:

```
countries_map = {country: continent
                 for continent,countries in continents.items()
                 for country in countries}
```

output:

```
{'Canada': 'North America',
 'Mexico': 'North America',
 'United States': 'North America'}
```

Then proceed as:

```
df['Continents'] = df['Country'].map(countries_map)
```